# RVS Argument of Scipy Kstest for non-standard (Landau) distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working with Landau distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_distribution) and am trying to use scipy.stats.kstest to get a goodness of fit statistic.

Since the Landau distribution is a non-standard distribution for scipy, I am using an import from ROOT (the CERN C++ package) as a custom, callable CDF as per the stats.kstest documentation. I also have a 1-D array of my measured/empirical data.

As it stands, I have the following definition of my kstest function:

```
def get_ks_test(fit_info):

    coeffs, erfc_bool = fit_info[0], fit_info[4]
    (mu,sigma,A_l,A_e) = coeffs

    def Lcdf(x):
        return [A_l*Math.landau_cdf(i,sigma,mu) for i in x]

    def integrand(x):
        return A_e*erfc((x-mu)/sigma)

    def total_cdf(x):
        return Lcdf(x) + quad(integrand,0,x)

    scatter_data = pdf_fit_return[3]

    return kstest(scatter_data,total_cdf)
```

Here `Lcdf` and `integrand` are combined to form my callable CDF function. The problem arises with the first argument of kstest, the "rvs" array `scatter_data`. As I understand it, the "rvs" argument is supposed to be an array of observations to match with the distribution in question. But in the source code, "rvs" is sent as an argument to "cdf". This makes no sense to me; shouldn't the CDF be a function of x, not of the data it's supposed to match?

When I pass my `scatter_data` as the first argument of kstest, it tries to plug those values into `total_cdf` when that function is supposed to take an argument in x. I don't know if I am failing to understand the usage of rvs/cdf here or what, but the way the kstest function is designed seems backwards to me.

I would like to be able to give kstest my data, my intended distribution (a callable CDF) but all the examples I've seen online involve included or standard distributions (normal, beta, etc.).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the CDF should be a function of `x`, not of the data it's supposed to match"?  I don't understand what you think is different about `x` (where did `x` come from, anyway?), and `scatter_data`.  The idea is that `scatter_data` is potentially a random sample from the distribution associated with the CDF, so it certainly makes sense that the CDF can and will be evaluated at `scatter_data` by the KS test.

Comment: You have `scatter_data = pdf_fit_return[3]`, but we don't know what `pdf_fit_return` is.  I suspect, however, that you have already tried to fit your data to the distribution, and `pdf_fit_return[3]` is *not* the original data.  What is it?

Comment: `pdf_fit_return[3]` is an array with values that, when plotted against x, form a distribution roughly Landau-like. It is the original data. I have used scipy.optimize to get the parameters for a continuous Landau distribution to match that data and I want to quantify the goodness of fit. x is the dependent axis that both the scatter data and the distribution are plotted against. It makes no sense to me for a CDF (a data distribution in x) to take as an argument the data distribution it is supposed to be compared against, as per the KS test.

Comment: So `x` is the "event space" of your distribution, which for the Landau distribution is the real line.  A random sample of the Landau distribution would be a subset of the real line.  That is what `kstest` expects for the first argument.

Comment: So I should pass my "event space" array of evenly spaced values in x? I'm confused how the kstest is comparing data to distribution if it's not being given the data, rather being given the axis along which the data is distributed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your actual, original input to this whole process is.  You say you have a "1-D array of my measured/empirical data".   Are you trying to model that data as a random sample from the Landau distribution?  Please explain exactly what that data is.

Comment: I have an array of data that is more-or-less Landau distributed. It was originally randomly sampled from a Landau distribution but was slightly altered. When graphed as a histogram over x, the data forms a Landau-ish distribution. I then used an optimize package to match a Landau distribution to that data. My data is an array of histogram values: [0,1,5,4,...] with the same length as an associated array of x values [0,1,2,3,4...]. Given that data and my optimized distribution, I want a quantitative measure of the goodness of fit of the optimized distribution. x is the dependent axis for both.

Comment: Ah, I see.  `kstest` is not the right function for fitting the data derived from the histogram.  I don't think `kstest` will help you measure the goodness of the fit produced by your optimization package.   The input to `kstest` would have to be the very first thing you started with, "an array of data that is more-or-less Landau distributed", and in that case, `kstest` would know nothing about the fit that you already performed.

Comment: Whoops, I said "`kstest` would know nothing about the fit that you already performed", but that's not true, because it looks like the CDF that you are testing the random sample with uses the parameters from the fit.  So try givng the *original*, more-or-less Landau distributed data as the first argument to `kstest`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, just realized what I've been confusing.